# Love2d extern image breaks shader

Tags: graphics, lua, glsl, shader, love2d

I'm making a blend mode shader in Love2D (version 0.9.2, which I cannot update). However, with it being broken already, I have it cut down to this:

```
[[
    extern Image base;

    vec4 effect(vec4 tint, sampler2D tex, vec2 tex_coords, vec2 pos) {
        vec4 color = texture2D(tex, tex_coords);

        return color;
    }
]]
```

Problem is, the moment I use

```
shader:send("base", image)
```

In love.draw(), it results in a black (empty) screen.

What could I possibly be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problems:

A. I was not USING the 'base' variable in the shader
B. the console library 'Cupid' eats up certain graphical errors, so I was not getting any response.

To fix the shader, simply add something like the following to the 'effect' function:

```
vec4 baseColor = Texel(base, tex_coords);
```

This way, the extern Image base is kept rather than discarded after compilation for efficiency.